# Why @ConditionalOnMissingBean is invoked before the bean it should check?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

In my Spring Boot application I want beans to be created only if a module is not enabled.

In CoreConfig I've defined two beans (geocoder and travelDistanceCalculator)
annotated with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` referencing the interfaces those beans should initialize.

```
@Configuration
class CoreConfig {

    private val logger = loggerFor<CoreConfig>()

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(Geocoder::class)
    fun geocoder(): Geocoder {
        logger.warn("no Geocoder bean instance has been provided. Instantiating default.")

        return object : Geocoder {
            override fun getGeocode(address: String) = Coordinates.Unavailable
        }
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(TravelDistanceCalculator::class)
    fun travelDistanceCalculator(): TravelDistanceCalculator {
        logger.warn("no TravelDistanceCalculator bean instance has been provided. Instantiating default.")

        return object : TravelDistanceCalculator {
            override fun getTravelDistanceInKm(origin: Coordinates, destination: Coordinates) = Double.NaN
        }
    }

    // other beans definitions...
}
```

Then GeolocationConfig defines a bean (HereApiClient) implementing both Geocoder and TravelDistanceCalculator interfaces.

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty("app.geolocation.enable")
class GeolocationConfig {

    @Bean
    fun hereApiClient(
        geolocationProperties: GeolocationProperties,
        restTemplate: RestTemplate
    ): HereApiClient =
        HereApiClient(restTemplate, geolocationProperties)

}
```

`app.geolocation.enable` is defined as `true` in application.yml.

What happens here is that, on startup, geocoder and travelDistanceCalculator default beans defined in CoreConfig are initialized even if GeolocationConfig is enabled and HereApiClient is initialized shortly after them.

What am I missing here?

Comment: are both configurations in same jar?

Comment: Yes, in the same jar

Comment: Ok, so maybe you could use ```@ConditionalOnProperty(name="app.geolocation.enable",havingValue="false") ``` on ```CoreConfig```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@ConditionalOn(Missing)Bean` is intended to be used on auto-configuration classes. [see javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnBean.html)
If used in common configiruation-classes then the outcome depends on whichever configuration is loaded first. See andy-wilkinson answer

In your case you could easily use the same property (you are already providing) to configure the correct beans.

Use `@ConditionalOnProperty(name="app.geolocation.enable")` on `GeolocationConfig`

Use `@ConditionalOnProperty(name="app.geolocation.enable",havingValue="false")` on/in `CoreConfig`

*EDIT*

Use `@ConditionalOnProperty(name="app.geolocation.enable",havingValue="false",matchIfMissing = true)` if you want the `CoreConfig` to be used if the property is missing.

Comment: I was thinking _core module shouldn't know anything about geolocation module_, that's why I didn't refer to "app.geolocation.enable", but since properties and configs are in the same module I was just overthinking.

Comment: @noiaverbale if you really want _core module shouldn't know anything about geolocation module_ you should go for Andy's approach. On the other hand, you 'need'  a property to configure ```GeolocationConfig``` so... A small improvement could be that ```CoreConfig``` is used on absence of that property. see edit

Comment: havingValue="false" - and what happens if one defines "app.geolocation.enable=something"? The fallback bean will not be created, the main bean will not be created either, but still there will be no sensible error message about offending value being non-boolean because, well, we cannot tell Spring to expect boolean, right?

Answer (score 4):

`ConditionalOnMissingBean` is dependent on the order in which `@Configuration` classes are processed and their beans are defined. In your example, I suspect that `CoreConfig` is being processed, its conditions evaluated, and its beans defined before your `hereApiClient` bean has been defined. As a result, when the missing bean conditions are evaluated, there is no matching bean found and the `geocoder` and `travelDistanceCalculator` beans are defined.

The javadoc for `ConditionalOnMissingBean` makes the following recommendation:

> The condition can only match the bean definitions that have been processed by the application context so far and, as such, it is strongly recommended to use this condition on auto-configuration classes only. If a candidate bean may be created by another auto-configuration, make sure that the one using this condition runs after.

You could follow this recommendation by using `@Order` on your configuration classes. Alternatively (and preferably, in my opinion) you could make `CoreConfig` an auto-configuration class by listing it in `META-INF/spring.factories` under the `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration` key and moving it to a package where it will not be picked up by component scanning.

Comment: Auto-configuration classes looks to me like _over-engineering_ in my case, but thank you for your answer